# Vue - property (object) not defined in child component

Tags: javascript, properties, vuejs2, vue-component

I am receiving error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: task is not defined".` --> `{{ task.title }}`. I understood what it's mean, but I can't understand why. 
I looked into many examples and how I understand main points is to pass property from parent component like this: `v-bind:some_prop` or `:some_prop` and in child component define `prop: ['some_prop']`. Maybe it's not allowed to pass js object, however I saw an example where they were passing it like this: `:some_prop="{['first', 'second']}`. Than I suppose, that object could be passed, but how?

Tasks.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="tasks_wrapper">
            <div id="elements_wrapper">
                <div class="title">Tasks for today</div>
                <hr class="delimiter" />
                <ul id="tasks_list">
                    <task v-for="(task, index) in tasks_list" v-bind:task="task" v-bind:key="index"></task>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Task from './Task.vue';

    export default {

        components: {
            Task
        },
        data() {
            return {
                tasks_list: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.tasks();
            setInterval(this.tasks, 300000);
        },
        methods: {
            tasks() {
                let that = this;
                axios.get('http://localhost/tasks')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        that.tasks_list = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log('Error! Could not reach the API. ' + error);
                    });
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

Task.vue:

```
<template>
    <li>
        <div class="title" :style="style">{{ task.title }}</div>
    </li>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: ['task'],

        data() {
            return {
                completed: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            style: function () {
                if (task.status === 'completed') {
                    this.completed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this `this.task.status` instead of `task.status` & you need to replace `prop` to `props` like below inside your `Task.vue`

```
export default {
        props: ['task'],

        data() {
            return {
                completed: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            style: function () {
                if (this.task.status === 'completed') {
                    this.completed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please explain, why I need 'this' here this.task.status, but dont need it in {{ task.title }}